# What type of screw head shape is this?

Tags: tool-identification

I’m trying to search for this screw but cannot find a comparable head shape. I know it’s an Allen/hex, but I’m talking about the overall shape, it’s like a ‘reverse button-head’, or ‘anti-pan head’?
I have searched Amazon and even google images, but that hasn’t been fruitful.

Excuse the sub-par photograph. I *think* you can see the shape well enough:

[image]

Comment: They're common on bikes, but I don't know what they're called either

Comment: I've been looking and I really can't find a source or name.  The closest is a flanged button head.  I've seen plenty of unusual curved-head screws on bikes, such as button heads with the same size socket normally used for a cap head

Comment: Same! It’s crazy because I’ve seen them on things like bikes like you say. But not to buy as-is. Super annoying!

Comment: My last idea is to look at the brand of my old mudguards and see if they're sold as spares, and given a name there. My regular screw suppliers (work) don't do them and more surprisingly I can't find them on ebay

Comment: I mean, they are not in McMaster Carr either, which is normally my go to for this kind of question. Good idea, or if I can find them on something being sold currently, give them an email? They might be nice to me? Hehe

Comment: The ones I've got were fitted to my genesis bike when I bought it new. On an unrelated issue they weren't very helpful

Comment: I've found a product photo with them in, a spares kit for [Norco suspension](https://www.evanscycles.com/norco-2013-sight-upper-shock-pivot-bolt-EV195729).  I've come to suspect that as they're functionally the same as flanged buttonheads, the difference is one of styling and there may be no standard term.  I haven't exactly given up but I've run out of idea for now (no branding on the surviving bits of my old back mudguard)

Answer (score 2):

Taper Head Bolt seems to be the most technical way I can find it referred as. As common, "Water Bottle Cage Bolts" is used.

Taper cap bolt
[image: Taper cap bolt]

M5x12mm Titanium Hex Key Washer Taper Head Bolt Bike MTB Water Bottle Cage Screw
[image: M5x12mm Titanium Hex Key Washer Taper Head Bolt Bike MTB Water Bottle Cage Screw]

MCTi Mountain MTB Bike Water Bottle Cage Titanium Allen Hex Tapered Head Bolts Screw M5x12mm Washer Head 4 Packed Colorful
[image: MCTi Mountain MTB Bike Water Bottle Cage Titanium Allen Hex Tapered Head Bolts Screw M5x12mm Washer Head 4 Packed Colorful]

Bolts & Fasteners 6pcs Titanium Ti Rainbow M5x20 Bolts Allen Hex Tapered Head Screw
[image: Bolts & Fasteners 6pcs Titanium Ti Rainbow M5x20 Bolts Allen Hex Tapered Head Screw]

Precision Anodized Water Bottle Cage Bolts
[image: Precision Anodized Water Bottle Cage Bolts]

Titanium M5x12mm with Washers Bicycle Water Bottle Cage Hex Bolts Pack of 4
[image: Titanium M5x12mm with Washers Bicycle Water Bottle Cage Hex Bolts Pack of 4]

Alloy Water Bottle Cage Bolts
[image: Alloy Water Bottle Cage Bolts]

Comment: Nice answer, but it needs more photos.

Comment: @rebusB I tried, but failed to find more examples. :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to this
[image: bicycle bolt.]

[M5 Black Anodized Bolt](https://www.performancebike.com/dimension-black-anodized-bolt-bo0000000312/p541014)
Description:
Tapered socket head with 4mm broach M5 diameter bolt, 0.8mm thread pitch

Comment: And yet every other hit I've seen for "tapered socket head" is for a more conical shape e.g. https://www.pro-bolt.com/stainless/stainless-steel-bolts-tapered-socket-cap.html

Comment: Yeah, think it’s a bicycle thing.